# Bootstrap 3.3.6 Grid boundaries not providing a rigid structure

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to get familiar with Bootstrap and the Grid. I am attempting to create the following macro layout:

```
===================================================
| PageTitle              |________________________|
|________________________| +1  |________| img| img|
| Make a choice.         |_____|________|____|____|
|                        |                        |
===================================================
```

The main element is a jumbotron, within which there is a row. I then split the row into two `<div>` elements of `class="col-xs-12"` each (I want the left panel to remain above the right on mobile).

The left panel is further split into two rows with some text content.

The right panel contains a row, split into two sections once again. The left and right sections are both `class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3"`. This is to ensure that on smaller screens they each fit one on top of the other and fill the entire horizontal space. A row and further column substructure splits the space as shown.

Here is my code so far: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/g40vahnn/)

As you will be able to see, the layout is behaving as I would expect at xs size (below 768px). However, at the larger size, rows and columns in the right panel are overlapping each other, and the images have disappeared.

Any guidance in understanding why the grid is not operating as I would expect (i.e. as a table that intelligently reflows at different screen sizes), would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason you have `height` and `width` attributes on practically every element? I think you need to read the Bootstrap documentation as you don't appear to have an understanding of how the grid system actually works.  You also have a lot of `div` tags with a class of `row` except no columns inside them.  Overall, you mixing and matching random classes.

Comment: The height and width were there just to see if I could force a col-*-* to take up the right amount of the screen at the appropriate resolution. It didn't work. Removing them makes the columns overlap.

Comment: There are two rows without columns inside them, and these happen to display exactly as I want them to. The relevant part of the example, doesn't have this problem. I have actually read the bootstrap docs from top to bottom, which is why I'm asking this question--perhaps I've misinterpreted how the grid is supposed to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The grid structure on the right panel of small device seems to be wrong.

In the code snippet of your JSFiddle. On line number `17 and 32`, change `class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"` to `class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6"`.

This would make the images appear again.

**Updated:**

Ofcourse you can, You just need to change the approach your taking to construct,  and any structure is possible. Check [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s51250c3/). It shows columns under rows and rows under columns structure in a way simple to understand.

In your case what you need to do is at the top-most level divide your structure into 4 columns and do whatever you want inside each column.

**Easiest way to approach and understand any complicated structure :**

- First Determine how many columns your structure needs. The top-most should always be divided taking columns into consideration.
- Once columns are determined, Consider each column as a full width page(ignoring the other columns for time being) and divide again and so on.

Simple :-)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It did make the images reappear. My question pertained more to the alignment of columns next to each other, and why they would often end up overlapping. My understanding was that there are 12 horizontal columns to work with, and that I could subdivide the space with rows and column structures as long as the overall number of columns in the top level at a particular resolution ended up being 12. This is not the case from my experiments. 12 columns only get laid out correctly within one single row element. Further layers of rows causes layout issues.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I think it answers your questions.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil! That's exactly the intuition I was after--now it makes a lot more sense :)

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if the question I was asking was not clear in any way, but here is what I was attempting to do. Hopefully, seeing the answer side-by-side with the question will help clarify:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
    <h2>
      PageTitle.
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-1 text-center">
    <h2>
      +1
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
    <div class="statsbox">
      <div class="statsbaryes">
      </div>
      <div class="statsbarno">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 text-center">
    <img id="image1" alt="image" src="http://www.intuac.com/userport/john/btpc5/baboon.png" class="img-circle" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 text-center">
    <img id="image2" alt="face" src="http://www.intuac.com/userport/john/btpc5/baboon.png" class="img-circle" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.statsbaryes {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 20%;
}
.statsbarno {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 80%;
}
.statsbox {
  height: 66px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid grey;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z9jvnahd/

As mentioned in my comment to Nikhil's answer, the issue came from my misunderstanding that I could have as many layers of row/column subdivisions as I wanted to help structure the layout, as long as there were 12 columns for each logical row on the screen. However, this is not the case, and the columns seem to need to be all grouped together in a signle top-level row to behave correctly--from my experimentation.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I think it answers your questions.